# How to make the footer on scroll fade in, in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, footer

I'm trying to make the footer fade in after 1000px, but it jumps on the screen immediately.
I'm making this in Jquery so I tried the fadeIn(),but with zero result.
I also tried to make the footer disappear with the fadeout(), but also with zero result.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

```
//effect to make the footer appear after some px
  jQuery(function($){
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y > 1000) {
            $('footer').show().fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $('footer').hide().fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<!--Footer-->
<div id="ft" class="page-wrap">
  <main>
    <section>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <small>
      - Footer -
      <p>Contenido Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </small>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is exactly what you looking for:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/sqzdq1rm/3/)

**JQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
function footer()
{
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if(scroll>20)
    { 
        $("footer").fadeIn("slow").addClass("show");
    }
    else
    {
        $("footer").fadeOut("slow").removeClass("show");
    }

}
footer();
});
```

Comment: Exemple is fine except there is no reason to make the `function footer()`

Comment: there is a reason if someone wants to use it multiple time at multiple conditions.  kind of reusable function.

Comment: Then the function should be declared outside the scroll event.